# Remove a last item from each sublist nested in two zipped lists

Tags: python

I work with python inside Dynamo and I've a zipped lists (curves, vectors) with nested sublists in both lists, and I want to remove the last item in each sublist

I tried to use zip function in the two level lists, but I get empty lists

```
curves = [[curve1, curve2, curve3, curve4, curve5], [curve6, curve7, curve8, curve9],[curve10,curve11, curve12], [curve13, curve14]]

vectors= [[vector1, vector2, vector3, vector4, vector5], [vector6, vector7, vector8, vector9],[vector10,vector11, vector12], [vector13, vector14]]

curves1 = []
temp1 = []
vectors1= []
temp2 = []

for i, j in zip(range((0,len(curves)), range(0, len(vectors))):
    for c, v in zip(range(0, len(i)-1), range(0, len(j)-1):      
        temp1.append(c)      
        temp2.append(v)  
    curves1.append(temp1)  
    vectors1.append(temp2)  
    temp1 =[]  
    temp2 = []
OUT = curves1 , vectors1
```

the result should be:

```py
curves1 = [[curve1, curve2, curve3, curve4], [curve6, curve7, curve8],[curve10,curve11], [curve13]]

vectors1= [[vector1, vector2, vector3, vector4], [vector6, vector7, vector8],[vector10,vector11], [vector13]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to zip the lists. Usually you use `zip` when you want to use the items of multiple iterables simultaneously. That's not the case here. You just want to do the same operation to multiple lists.

This is enough:

```
curves1 = [sublist[:-1] for sublist in curves]
vectors1 = [sublist[:-1] for sublist in vectors]
```

Or, in the spirit of [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), make a function that returns a list with truncated sublists and feed curves and vectors into that.

```
def truncate_sublists(inp_list: list):
    return [sublist[:-1] for sublist in inp_list]

curves1 = truncate_sublists(curves)
vectors1 = truncate_sublists(vectors)
```

Comment: It's seems so easy without zip function ... I’ll try and see how it goes

Comment: It's  easest and fastest and it's work fine

Answer (score 1):

```
curves = [['curve1', 'curve2', 'curve3', 'curve4', 'curve5'], ['curve6', 'curve7', 'curve8', 'curve9'], ['curve10', 'curve11', 'curve12'], ['curve13', 'curve14']]
vectors = [['vector1', 'vector2', 'vector3', 'vector4', 'vector5'], ['vector6', 'vector7', 'vector8', 'vector9'], ['vector10', 'vector11', 'vector12'], ['vector13', 'vector14']]

curves1 = []
vectors1 = []

for sublist1, sublist2 in zip(curves, vectors):
    curves1.append(sublist1[:-1])
    vectors1.append(sublist2[:-1])


print(curves1)
print(vectors1)
```

Hope it works